Android compose how can I apply animation on Column Arrangement?
I want to dynamically change the verticalArrangement value when placing UI with Column in Android Compose.
The code is simple
It looks roughly like this, and it works well
var arrangement by remember { mutableStateOf(Arrangement.Center) }
Column(
    verticalArrangement = arrangement
) {
    Text(text = "hello")

    Button(
        onClick = {}
    )
}

However, the UI placement looks disjointed and visually incomplete.
We want the UI layout to slide smoothly when arrangement is changed.
How can I do this?

Does this answer your question? Animate Column from Arrangement.Center to Arrangement.Top
